# DBPedia sub-categories

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to collect all sub-categories of a given category on DBPedia, but I'm not sure what is wrong with the following query:

```
PREFIX category: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core/>
select distinct ?subcategory where {
  category:American_pop_rock_singers skos:broader ?subcategory
}
```

I thought that the `skos:broader` property was what I needed to use.

Comment: `PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>`. Hash, not slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by @Stanislav Kralin in the comments above:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
```

Comment: Also, the pattern for subcategories should be rather `?subcategory skos:broader category:American_pop_rock_singers`.